# filter array using a second array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple javascript array:

```
var earningarray = [
  ["2015-12-29T23:59:59+00:00", 3],
  ["2015-12-28T23:59:59+00:00", 3]
];
```

I have another array.

```
var paddingarray = [
  ["2015-12-19T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-20T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-21T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-22T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-23T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-24T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-25T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-26T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-27T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-28T23:59:59+00:00", 0]
];
```

What I am trying to achieve is to remove from paddingarray the rows where they exist in earningsarray based on the datestamp (first column).

I have tried doing it with this function:

```
newarray = paddingarray.filter(function(val) {
  return earningarray[0].indexOf(val[0]) == -1;
});
```

However it does not filter the array correctly and outputs exactly the same as the original paddingarray. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Array.prototype.some()`

```js
var earningarray = [
  ["2015-12-29T23:59:59+00:00", 3],
  ["2015-12-28T23:59:59+00:00", 3]
];

var paddingarray = [
  ["2015-12-19T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-20T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-21T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-22T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-23T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-24T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-25T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-26T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-27T23:59:59+00:00", 0],
  ["2015-12-28T23:59:59+00:00", 0]
];

var newarray = paddingarray.filter(function(val) {
  return !earningarray.some(function(v) {
    return v[0] === val[0]
  })
});

console.log(paddingarray.length, newarray.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function tries to find values from `paddingarray` in `earningarray[0]`, which is the first element of that array, rather than in the first element of each of the elements of that array.

Try this instead:

```
paddingarray.filter(function(val) {
    return earningarray.filter(function(val2) {
        return val2[0] == val[0]
    }).length == 0;
});
```